# InlineButton should change value (date) in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

Im trying to implement an Inline button inside a table, that immediately changes / writes the Date of today in the database.
The click on the Button "change" should write the actual Date in the Database.

I already found a way to create an inline button to change a boolean value inside the Database. To activate / deactivate a Product for example.

Now I nearly need the same only with the fact, that when I press the Button it should write todays date inside the Database.

**Creating the Button**

```html
function doCustomRenderColumn($fieldName, $fieldData, $rowData, &$customText, &$handled)
        { 
            if ($fieldName == 'active') {
                $dataAttributes = sprintf('data-id="%s" data-active="%s"', $rowData['id'], $fieldData);
                $customText = '<span class="product-info" style="display: none;" ' . $dataAttributes. '></span>' . $customText;
                $customText .=  '<button class="btn btn-default inline-button" style="margin-left: 25px;">Change</button>';
                $handled = true;
            }
        }
```

**Handling parameters and executing the query**

```html
function DoPrepare() {
            if (GetApplication()->IsGETValueSet('id') && GetApplication()->IsGETValueSet('active')) {
                $id = GetApplication()->GetGETValue('id');
                $active = GetApplication()->GetGETValue('active');
                $sql = "UPDATE product SET active=$active WHERE id=$id";
                $this->GetConnection()->ExecSQL($sql);
                echo json_encode(array("active" => $active));
                exit;
            }
```

**Handling the button click and calling AJAX**

```html
// OnAfterPageLoad event body
 function prepareInlineButtons() {
    $('button.inline-button').click(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var checkboxControl = self.siblings('.pg-row-checkbox');
        var productId = self.siblings('.product-info').data('id');
        var activity = self.siblings('.product-info').data('active');
        $.getJSON(location.href, {id: productId, active: activity == 1 ? 0 : 1}, function (data) {
            self.siblings('.product-info').data('active', data.active);
            if (data.active == 1) {
                checkboxControl.addClass('checked')
            }
            else {
                checkboxControl.removeClass('checked')
            }
        })
    })
}

prepareInlineButtons();
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `click(function()`, but this don't gonna work.
This just work for objects already on screen at loading time.

Try use [.on()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp) jquery function, like `$('button.inline-button').on('click', function()`